# Does Silver Lining negate a creeper requirement?

Tags: fluxx

If, for example, You Also Need a Baked Potato is in play or the goal is War=Death, what is the effect of the Silver Lining card, which states that creepers cannot prevent you from winning?

Comment: Which version of fluxx is this for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally, if a player has a creeper in play that player cannot win even if they meet the requirements for winning.

If the requirements for winning also require 1 or more creepers (such as in the War=Death goal) the player can win if they have those creepers, and must have those creepers in order to win, however if the player also has any other creepers (such as taxes) in play they cannot win. In this case, a player must have Death and War, but must not have any other creepers in play, in order to win.

The Silver Lining card only removes the requirement that creepers prevent the player from winning. It does nothing else to the creepers or to the requirements. So if you have a goal: War = Death, you can still win if you have War, Death, Taxes, and the Silver Lining card is in play.

"You also need the potato" places the requirement that the baked potato must be one of your cards in addition to the rest of the requirements in order to win. When that card is in play you cannot win without the potato, and you must have the potato in order to win, regardless of whether or not the silver lining is in play.

Ultimately, when a creeper is part of the requirements for a goal or a win condition that creeper in that case does not prevent the player from winning by achieving that goal regardless of whether or not there is a silver lining.

Answer (score 1):

I would have to disagree with youngjohn.  For example: You need a side of potato rule is in play, and the current goal is All you need is love.  If you already have the "Love" keeper in front of you, why haven't you won yet?  Because a creeper card (or lack of a creeper) is affecting your ability to win.

By playing the silver linings new rule, you are effectively doing two things.  Number one, you are saying a creeper card can no longer stop you from winning.  Therefor, NOT having a certain creeper card will not stop you from winning if you have met the goal.

Also, the need a side of potato rule is a contradictive  rule  to the silver linings.  The one that is played second should superceed the one played first.   Either way, you win if you've met the current goal.

Comment: I suppose we disagree, but I've seen it played both ways. IMHO I believe that if the All you need is love goal is in place and you have a creeper, and you have the silver lining in play, it is not the creeper preventing you from winning, but rather the fact that you have not satisfied the needs of the goal that is preventing you from winning. In other words, all creepers come with the implied rule "You cannot win the game if this is in front of you. (unless it is part of a current goal)." Silver lining removes that implied rule from all creepers. It does not change the fact that:

Comment: "All you need is Love." requires you to have no other cards in play in front of you other than "Love" in order to achieve the goal.

Comment: Essentially, with the Silver Lining in play it is not the creeper card preventing you from winning, but the goal card preventing you from winning. In my opinion. But it can be fun to play either way.